# Using C++ library on website

Tags: android, c++, web

I'm about to write a large amount of code in C++ for maximum portability. I need this code to be able to run on a website and on an Android application through JNI. Although Java is technically also an option here, I may want to use this library in other projects in the future which will all be C++ based and I want to get the advantage of native speed because it's a math related library.

My question is what the best option is to run this code on a web site. The website itself doesn't have to be written in C++ just like the Android application itself is mostly written in Java.

I can see the following options:

- Write a PHP module to interface with this library
- Write a server in C++ for the API of the site that the site written in PHP accesses
- Write a fastcgi server

What do you think is my best option here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The choice is obviously yours and all of the options sound great but I think using factcgi with something like `WT` or `CPPCMS` will be awesome. Take a look at both of them they are wonderful libraries for this task, I prefer `CPPCMS` but I think that depend on your need

Answer (score 0):

What about a good old cgi programm? Is it penalty of starting up a process too big to justify the higher complexity of fastcgi?

Comment: I think it is in this case because scalability is important.

Comment: it depends on the runtime characteristics of your programm. If it runs long and computes a lot the cost of creating a new Process for each request may be insignificant

Comment: The program should typically respond within 10-20 ms.